# sum of two different rows(salary) in a table

Tags: sql, firebird

How can i get (salary of Mr.Smith in the fist row +salary of Mr.Wong in the second row) of my Firebird sql like the following table?

I tried

```
Select sum(column a +column b)
```

it didn't work .
I get Null.

```
Name    Salary
Smith   4000
Wong    3000
John    3300
...     ....
```

Comment: Please include a description of the table structure.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.  And please show the real, full SQL query.

Comment: please post your real data and what you need to mine from that data......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the `coalesce` operator.

```
select sum(coalesce(columna, 0) + coalesce(columnb, 0))
```

cause if any part is null, result will be null.

if you're talking of row instead of columns :

```
SELECT SUM(Salary)
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name IN ('Smith', 'Wong')
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
SELECT name,salary FROM table WHERE name 'smith'
UNION
SELECT name,salary FROM table WHERE name 'wong'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, salary FROM salaries WHERE name LIKE 'Smith' OR name LIKE 'Wong'
```

or this, if you want the totals, too:

```
SELECT name, salary FROM salaries WHERE name LIKE 'Smith' OR name LIKE 'Wong' GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP
```

I have put salaries as your salaries table, but you need to change that to whatever name you have for that table.